# SQL Server 2008 Vs SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows-server-2008

The performance of SQL Server 2000 database is not improving with the latest multi-core processors.   I think SQL Server 2000 is not capable of utilising these cores. So, I plan to switch to SQL Server 2008.

Before that I want to know whether SQL Server 2008 will perform better with Quad-core Intel Xeon processors ?  DB Size will be around 5-6 GB.

Comment: Do you know that the cores are not being utilized? Do you have measurements? Screenshots of task manager where only some core are pegged and others are idled? Are you sure the bottleneck is not memory or storage?

Comment: Probably this will get better attention at server fault.

Comment: A fully-functional 180-day trial version is available. Why not just download it and see for yourself?

Comment: While general answers can be given there is no substitute for your own performance testing that exercises the usage pattern that you have. Everything else is guessing. Also SQL Server 2000 is now out of mainstr4eam support, and less than 2 years from the end of all support: time to start planning an upgrade anyway.

Answer (score 1):

if you were really serious about getting your query workload to use multiple-processors / cores more often.. I'd probably take a look at decreasing your 'cost threshold for parallelism' from the default 5 to maybe 4 or 3.  I've noticed that this helps quite a bit on SQL 2000 with a decent core count.

Answer (score 0):

The performance of database depends largely on applications. I think it would be the best of your interest to test it yourself.

To answer your question, a [website](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/joe_chang/archive/2008/08/24/large-query-performance-from-sql-server-2000-to-2008-32-64-bit.aspx) mentioned **almost 3 times performance increase** on Quad-core Intel Xeon.

In addition to Marcelo Cantos 's comment, you can download SQL Server 2008 from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=265f08bc-1874-4c81-83d8-0d48dbce6297&displaylang=en#Instructions).